# Fan beam tomographic projections in Mathematica

Tags: image-processing, projection

I am embarking on a little project to redo some of my old MATLAB image processing code in *Mathematica*.

I am particularly interested in tomography, and I know of the `Radon` and `InverseRadon` functions that are now in *Mathematica*. But it seems there are no direct equivalents of the MATLAB functions `fanbeam` and `ifanbeam` from the Image Processing Toolbox. (More information on what they do is in [this link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/fan-beam-projection-data.html).)

Is there any way I can use `Radon` and `InverseRadon` to reimplement fan beam projections in *Mathematica*? I am interested in solutions for both the arc and line geometry case, and would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Can you please explain what these MATLAB functions do and make the question self-contained?

Comment: Hi, I have given links to the documentation on the Matlab site, I hope the discussion there is clear. Thank you.

Comment: If memory serves, there are conversion formulae you can use to go between fan beam and parallel beam projections, after which you can use the built-in Radon functionality. That is, try to look at how `fan2para()` and `para2fan()` were implemented in MATLAB, and use those to convert into a form usable by `Radon[]`/`InverseRadon[]`.

Comment: Did you implement it?